# Eclipse refactor tool and ICU4J

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse on a Java project which involves ICU4J 3.4.4 which will be running on mobile devices.

The ICU4J 3.4.4 is a few megabytes and I need to cut this down. I am only using the Normalizer class

Is there an easy way in Eclipse to move the Normalizer class into a new project along with its dependencies on other classes and so forth? I tried the move feature but it only brings across the Normalizer class

I am also happy to use any other tool to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Eclipses actually packages a small "base" version of the ICU4J stuff. For example on this download page: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.7.1-201109091335/index.php, look for "com.ibm.icu.base" which is only 1/3MB. Hopefully this will be small enough.

Comment: Unfortunately the jar does not contain the com.ibm.icu.text.Normalizer class I need

Comment: I don't know of anything that will move the dependent classes, but you should be able to keep moving classes until it works. Or get the source and chop out what you don't need.